# eclipse 3.5 filter .git folder

Tags: git, eclipse-3.5

I'm using eclipse 3.5.2 and cannot seem to use "filter resources" to filter out .git folders in any of my projects for any of my perspectives: javascript, ruby, and php. I've tried adding the filter to plugin.xml as suggested [on this blog](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/4/20/Eclipse-showing-svnbase-files-in-Open-Resource-dialog) but it is for eclipse 3.4 and doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given project (at least Java), you should be able through its properties, to edit its Source Path, and add an exclusion rule like:

```
**/.git/
```

[alt text http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/2641/eclipseexclusionpattern.png](http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/2641/eclipseexclusionpattern.png)

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that as well except I did ".git" instead of "**/.git/"