# How to create an Eclipse folder resource filter in Java

Tags: eclipse, resources, filter, directory

The Eclipse folder properties dialog allows you to edit the resource filters ( see [eclipse 3.5 filter .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766435/eclipse-3-5-filter-git-folder)) . I would like to do the same programmatically. My current solution is to use internal code as shown below to include only file that match 'xml'. Does anyone know how to do this without the use of internal code?

Thanks in advance

```
folder.createFilter(
    IResourceFilterDescription.FILES | IResourceFilterDescription.INCLUDE_ONLY,
        new FileInfoMatcherDescription("NameofFolder",  
            "1.0-name-matches-false-false-xml"), 0, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is:

```
folder.createFilter( 
   IResourceFilterDescription.EXCLUDE_ALL | IResourceFilterDescription.FOLDERS, 
       new FileInfoMatcherDescription("org.eclipse.core.resources.regexFilterMatcher",
           "xml"), IResource.BACKGROUND_REFRESH, monitor);
```

Comment: I believe to make it recursive you would OR-ing IResourceFilterDescription.INHERITABLE

Comment: regex must match the whole filename so `xml` match only a file with exactly "xml" as name. If you want everything with "xml" extension, you must use a regex like the following `.*\\.xml` (it's a real regex, not just a string with * and ? wildcards)